# ruby get everything after last 

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following string in ruby.

```
string = 'filename.jpg'
```

How can I get everything after the last .? (returnning the file extenstion in this case)

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ruby's [`String#split()` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165)

```
irb(main):001:0> string="foo.tar.gz"
=> "foo.tar.gz"
irb(main):002:0> string.split(".")[-1]
=> "gz"
```

Comment: Naming the variable `string` was stupid :) name your variables something better. Leaving it in here to shame me.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.extname('filename.jpg').gsub('.', '')
```

OR

```
'filename.jpg'.split('.')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "some.file.ext"

str.match(/[^.]+?$/) # => #<MatchData "ext">
str.match(/[^.]+?$/)[0] # => "ext"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.scan(/\.(.*)/)[-1][-1]
#=> "jpg"
string.match(/\.(.*)/)[-1]
#=> "jpg"
string.split(".")[-1]
#=> "jpg"
```

Comment: oh yeah, there is about last dot